# Circumcenter of 3D triangle without causing integer overflow

Tags: geometry, 3d

Programming side:
Trying to implement a calculation for 3D triangle calculation.

Mathematical side:
I need a formula for this that does not use cross product. I have found a formula that uses the vectors of the sides and cross products, but the issue is that My triangles are so large, that i get 64bit integer overflow. Cross product gives a vector so long that its square magnitude is larger than 64 bit integer.

For tetrahedron i solved the issue by switching to the Matrix determinant formula, there the values don't get big enough. But for triangle in 3D i didn't find any matrix solution. Is there a way to calculate circumcenter of a 3D triangle with out using cross product?

The solution should use only integers. or rational numbers.

Comment: I assume three points on triangle are given??

Comment: @KingTut yes. 3 points are given.

Comment: The answer is already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658318/how-to-find-the-circumcenter-of-a-triangle-and-the-length-of-the-corresponding-r/2658411).

Comment: Just curious: since it’s rather unlikely that the circumcenter will have integer coordinates, why are you using integer arithmetic for your cross products?

Comment: This question is not at all a duplicate: the referred question is asking how to find the circumcenter, while this one is about why the computation is more overflow-prone for a triangle than for a tetrahedron. This is a quite interesting question in its own respect as it has an immediate implication on the implementation using exact arithmetic.

Comment: @g.kov: no, this does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: And why, exactly, 
for example, formula (1) for the circumcenter in 3d from
[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2658411/122782), 
which does not include cross-product,
is not the answer to this question?

Comment: @g.kov: isn't it obvious that there is no discussion of overflow nor why the behavior is different for triangles and tetrahedra ? By the way, this formula requires real numbers, which the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: So i edited the question a bit. So it should be more clear what i'm looking form. Rational numbers are fine, because the scale is so big that the decimal places can be ignored. The problem of cross product is its magnitude. If i take cross product of 2 vector both with coordinates near 200 000, i get a vector with huge magnitude, and it will overflow a 64bit integer. I could try to implement my own number type with 128 bits, but it would be better if it could be done within 64 bits, with using maybe some tricks on clever mathematics.

Comment: The solution that g.kov suggested has the sin and cos in there. I can't calculate them easily nor accuarately. Since im using integers and dot product requires vectors at magnitude of 1 (coordinates can be smaller than 1), i wont be able to use dot product to calculate cosine.

Comment: @MarkoTaht: It's just the current question title is misleading.
You need to adjust it to reflect the real problem you have,
like integer overflow etc. Btw, can you at least 
calculate the sides of this huge triangles w/o overflow?
Then you will be able to use cosine rule for rational approx. for .$\cos$
and use the other form of the formula in terms of $R,S$.

Comment: @g.kov Do you mean the length of the sides?  I have to try

Comment: @MarkoTaht: Try to adjust this version of the mentioned formula:
$O=A\cdot \frac{a^2\,(b^2+c^2-a^2)}{((b+c)^2-a^2)(a^2-(b-c)^2)}$
$+B\cdot \frac{b^2\,(a^2+c^2-b^2)}{((a+c)^2-b^2)(b^2-(a-c)^2)}$
$+C\cdot \frac{c^2\,(b^2+a^2-c^2)}{((b+a)^2-c^2)(c^2-(b-a)^2)}$
to suit your needs.

Comment: Hmm... i still keep getting totally wrong answers. But i have limited time and i cant spend all of it on solving this issue, so im gona manipulate what i currently have to work with the limitations of float type numbers(7 significant digits), just so that i get good enough result. But this is interesting i will probably return to this at a later date, when i have more time.

Answer (score 0):

A cross product free solution:

The following figure depicts the three vertices $A,B,C$ and the corresponding three vectors $a,b$,and $c$:

[image]

The task is to determine the perpendicular segment bisectors in the plane of $ABC$. In what follows I will compute the parametric equation of the brown line, the perpendicular bisector of $AC$ in the $ABC$ plane. The same procedure will provide the equation of the perpendicular bisectors to $AC$ or to $CB$.

First, determine the parametric equation of the line through $AB$. The direction vector can be $d=b-a$. So the equation is $$\operatorname{blue}(u)= (b-a)u+a.$$
Take an arbitrary point on the $AB$ line. Taking a specific $u$ the arbitrary point is given.

Second, determine the vector (red) pointing to the middle point of $AC$: $$\operatorname{red}=\frac12(c+a).$$
Third, calculate the brown vector pointing from the midpoint of $AB$ to the blue point on $AB$ belonging to the parameter $u$ chosen:

$$\operatorname{brown}(u)=\operatorname{blue}(u)-\operatorname{red}.$$

Finally, choose $u$ so that the brown vector be perpendicular to $c-a$. For this we have to solve the following equation:

$$\operatorname{brown}(u)\circ(c-a)=0$$
where $\circ$ is the sign of the scalar product.
If $u_0$ solves the equation above then the equation of the perpendicular bisector is $$\operatorname{brown(u_0)}t+\operatorname{red}.$$

Repeating this for another segment bisector we'll get another equation of a line in the same plane. The crossing point of these lines will be the circumcenter.

Comment: But can you compute the intersection without an overflow ?

Comment: &Yves Daoust: what is an overflow?

Comment: The question is specifically about overflow avoidance, so you should know.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: I missed that point. I will hava to think this over.

Answer (score 0):

The circumcenter of a tetrahedron is the intersection of three planes. Each plane is defined by two vertices, potentially giving $O(n^4)$ different planes ($n$ is the range of the coordinates).

For a triangle, the supporting plane enters into play. As it is defined by three vertices, the number of distinct possibilities is $O(n^6)$.

This explains why more accuracy is required: there are more possible locations of the center. These are rational numbers, and the denominators need to be larger.

Unfortunately, this is unescapable and you will have to resort to extended arithmetic (or equivalent tricks), or sacrifice accuracy.

Comment: For tetrahedron using matrices worked like charm but using the vectors and cross products i got overflow.

Comment: @MarkoTaht: what's the range of your coordinates ? A determinant *is* a cross-product (and more). Actually, the formula for the coordinates is the same, whether you see it as matrix computation or vector operations.

Comment: it shouldn't be bigger than (-200 000, 200 000). But the issue comes from the ones that are in these limits. Smaller ones work. But larger ones just get overflow and the results are a nonsense.